# Angular 2 - ngFor with Filter not seeing variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a component that sets count = 1.
I have an ngFor statement that I am trying to pass the value of count to in a filter like so...

```
<li *ngFor="let i of (data | myfilter:count)">
//do stuff...
</li>
```

The problem is that the even though I can clearly interpolate the count variable outside of the ngFor, and see its set to 1, the ngFor doesnt seem to see it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the filter is expecting a string instead of a number. Adding count.toString() resolved the issue.